# The use of std::bind with a binary operation function in C++

Tags: c++, stl, stdbind

I am trying to learn how the std::bind works. I wrote the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


using namespace std::placeholders;

int fun2(int i,int j)
{
   return i+j;
}


int fun(int i)
{
  return i;
}

int main()
{
 std::vector<int> v9={1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7};
 std::transform(v9.begin(),v9.end(),v9.begin(),[](int i){return i;}); //works
 std::transform(v9.begin(),v9.end(),v9.begin(),fun); //works
 std::transform(v9.begin(),v9.end(),v9.begin(),std::bind(fun,_1)); //works
 std::transform(v9.begin(),v9.end(),v9.begin(),std::bind(fun2,_1,_2)); //does not work
}
```

std::transform also accepts binary operation functions. So I tried to wrote fun2 and use std::bind (last line of the main) but it doesn't work. Can someone give me any example how std::bind use placeholders (2,3 or more)?

Comment: `std::transform` only passes one argument. Did you mean to do something like `std::bind(fun2, _1, 5)`?

Comment: Except when when it passes two: [(2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) :)

Comment: There's really no point using `std::bind` if you don't bind any of the arguments.

Comment: @jrok, My life has been changed forever. Thank you!

Comment: @sftrabbit you are right but it's not a real program, I am just trying to learn how std::bind works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overload of [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) that takes a binary functor takes four iterators, not three, since it operates on two input ranges, and not one. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

int fun2(int i,int j)
{
   return i+j;
}

int main()
{
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  std::vector<int> v1={1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7};
  std::vector<int> v2;
  std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v1.begin(), 
                 std::back_inserter(v2), std::bind(fun2,_1,_2));
  for (const auto& i : v2)
    std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, in real life you wouldn't use `std::bind` here.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. `std::transform(v9.begin(),v9.end(),v9.begin(),v9.end(),std::bind(fun2,_1,_2));`

Comment: @AvraamMavridis: Are you _certain_ that that code gives you the same error?  What is the full error?  (If Visual Studio, full error is in the "Output" window, NOT the "Error" Window)

Comment: @MooingDuck that code (in the comment) does not give any error, it compiles.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis right, it compiles, but will fail at runtime.

Comment: `std::transform(v9.begin(),v9.end(),v9.begin(),v9.begin(),std::bind(fun2,_1,_2));` is correct. I should have read cpp-reference more carefully.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis I added a working example (it does not do exactly the same as yours, but you get the idea).